# Counting in 2D Matrix

Tags: combinatorics

### Filling Matrix

https://www.codechef.com/VIT32020/problems/CCVITR31

The question asks us to :

Find the number of combinations in which at least one column or one row contains balls of only one color.

So we have N rows and N columns and if we select any row or column and color it with one of the 3 colors and the remaining boxes with any color that should give us the answer.

My Formula :$^{2N}$$C_1$ * $^3$$C_1$ * $3^{N^2 - N}$.

$^{2N}$$C_1$ -> Selecting 1 row or column from N rows + N columns

$^3$$C_1$ -> Coloring the selected row or column with Red/ Blue/ Green

$3^{N^2 - N}$ -> Coloring remaining (N^2 - N) boxes with any color Red/ Blue/ Green

But this approach is not matching with the input test cases.

Comment: You are double counting on a large scale. Consider the umpteen cases where both row 1 and row 2 are monochrome. You count each of then once when you select row 1 to be monochrome and again when you select row 2 to be monochrome.

Comment: @almagest Oh you are right I didn't notice that. Should I use 'Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion' (PIE) then? But I am not sure how PIE will simplify the calculations?

Comment: I doubt there is a simple answer. This is a coding problem, not a math problem.